# How to index a web site

Tags: asp.net, indexing, full-text-indexing

I'm asking on behalf of somebody, so I don't have too many details.

What options are available for indexing site content in an ASP.NET web site?  I suspect SQL Server's Full Text index may be used if the page content is stored in the database.  How would I index dynamic and static content if that content isn't stored in the DB, but in html and aspx pages themselves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We purchased Karamasoft [Ultimate Search](http://www.karamasoft.com/UltimateSearch/Features.aspx) several years ago. It is a search engine add-on for your web site. I like it because it is a simple tool that taught us searching on our site. It is pretty inexpensive and we knew we could buy later if we needed more or different features. We needed something that would give us searching without having to do a lot of programming.

Specifically, this tool is a web crawler. It will run on your web server and it will act like an end-user and navigate through your site keeping a record of your web pages, so when a real users searches, they are told the pages that have the content they want.

Keep that in mind it is acting like an end-user, so your dynamic data is indexed right along with the static stuff because it indexes the final web page. We needed this feature and it is what appealed to us the most.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [web crawler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_crawler) to crawl that site and add the content to a database which then is full text indexed. There are a number of web crawlers out there.

Answer (score 1):

Lucene is a well known open source tool that would help you here. The main branch is Java based but there is a .Net port too.

Main site: http://lucene.apache.org/
.Net port: http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/

Answer (score 0):

Having used several alternatives I would be loath to do anything other than [Google Site Search](http://www.google.com/sitesearch/).

The only reason I use SQL Full Text Search is to search through multiple columns.  It's really hard to implement it in any effective manner.